# OAuth2 Cannot authenticate for API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0

My application is divided into authentication for API and UI.
UI contains:

ClientId, ClientSecret, Tenant, Redirect URL

API contains:
ApiClientId, APPID URI, Tenant

I am able to obtain access token using:
UI_ClientId as client_id,
API_ClientId as scope
UI_ClientSecret and ofcourse Tenant

But when I add authentication on my API side through AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi, like following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                     {
                         Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                         options.Authority = $"{azureAdOptions.Instance}{azureAdOptions.TenantId}";
                         options.Audience = azureAdOptions.ClientId;
                         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                         {
                             ValidateAudience = true,
                             ValidateIssuer = true,
                             ValidIssuer = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAdOptions.TenantId}/v2.0"
```

While sending request im getting general error: "Object reference not set to an instance..."
without any details.

When I try to add authentication like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADBearer(options =>
                 {
                     Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                 });
```

I get unauthorized error message.

AzConfig in appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain",
    "TenantId": "tenantId",
    "ClientId": "ApiClientId",
    "ApiScopes": "https://xxx/tenatnId/APIAccess/Name.API"
  }
```

Please advice what I might`ve missed, cause its diving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify valid issuers then it is working as expected.

```
  options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[]
                {
                    $"{Configuration["AzureAd:ValidIssuer"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
                    $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/"
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using the built-in Microsoft stuff:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
            });
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.30" for .net 3.1. doesnt have AddMicrosoftAccount()